# Unit Test - How to verify if a class are equal to another?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to verify if a class are equal to another with Unit Tests.
I have a class like:

```
public class Class1 : Interface
{
     public Interface returnAnInstanceOfInterface()
     {
        Interface interface = new Class2();
        return interface;
     }
}
```

and I'm trying to test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestIfReturnAnInstanceOfInterface()
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    Interface expected = new Class2();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, class1.returnAnInstanceOfInterface());
}
```

My test fails, but the test result says: `Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Namespace.Class2>. Actual:<Namespace.Class2>.` What i'm doing wrong? Is there another way to do that?

Comment: "class are equal " - do you mean types are the same (like `class1.GetType()`) OR `class1.Equals(expected)` OR something completely different?

Comment: yes, I mean that types are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the instances are of the same class, you can do it this way.

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected.GetType(), class1.returnAnInstanceOfInterface().GetType());
```

Also you can use IsInstanceOfType static method if it is MsTest unit tests.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestIfReturnAnInstanceOfInterface()
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(class1.returnAnInstanceOfInterface(),typeof(Class2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Assert.IsInstanceOfType method:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestIfReturnAnInstanceOfInterface()
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(class1.returnAnInstanceOfInterface(), typeof(Class2));
}
```

or just assert on types equality